# Sending packets over tcp network

Tags: c#, networking, packet

I'm trying to send data between clients, when sending data over tcp it is a stream instead of a 'one send is one receive' function. therefore i wrote a little wrapper for a networkstream. It works, but am i missing something? is this a correct way to solve my problem?

My network knowledge is not that great.

(My async knowledge is also very limited, this is the first time using this, so if there is anything wrong with it, please let me know.)

For completeness i included my test code also:

Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        HandlerServer();
        HandleClients();

        while (true)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

handle functions:

```
    private static async void HandleClients()
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
            using (TcpMessageStream stream = new TcpMessageStream(client))
            {
                while (true)
                    await stream.SendAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
        }
    }

    private async static void HandlerServer()
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);

        server.Start();

        using (TcpClient cl = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
        using (TcpMessageStream stream = new TcpMessageStream(cl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected!!");
            while (true)
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(await stream.ReceiveAsync()));
        }
    }
```

Created class:

```
class TcpMessageStream : IDisposable
{
    NetworkStream _stream;
    public TcpMessageStream(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        _stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] prefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.LongLength);
        await _stream.WriteAsync(prefix);
        await _stream.WriteAsync(data);
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead += await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, bytesRead, 8 - bytesRead);

        } while (bytesRead < 8);

        var dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer);

        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[dataLength];

        bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead += await _stream.ReadAsync(messageBuffer, bytesRead, messageBuffer.Length - bytesRead);

        } while (bytesRead < messageBuffer.Length);

        return messageBuffer;
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources.
                _stream.Dispose();
            }

            // Clean up unmanaged resources here.
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~TcpMessageStream()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: async code actually doesn't run on a seperate thread. So your while loops will block the current thread and any other 'async' code won't be able to run. Consider starting a thread for handling the clients and the server code.

Comment: @JessedeWit But doesn't the 'await' inside the while loop give back the 'thread' to other code that needs executing when it is awaiting?

Comment: In theory, yes. But that other code it encounters will not be able to execute, because the current thread is occupied/working. `Console.Readline()` also blocks the current thread, meaning your thread will be free only when you are sending packets to clients. Your server side code may be fine, because the `ReceiveAsync` will free up the current thread.

Comment: @JessedeWit Ah yeah i see, thanks! i will do that in my actual project. But in theory if the `Console.Readline()` would be async aswell, this example code would be ok?

Comment: Yes, I think it should. (if you'd use `await Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`, which is also blocking) Note that you will not be able to catch any exceptions however, you you'll probably want to add some exception handling inside your async functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is a good idea. You have created a simple protocol that writes a length prefix before the data so that you know how much to read. This is very common, simple and efficient.

You can simplify the code a lot. `BinaryReader` has methods to read and write integers and byte arrays. You can read a byte array of an exact size. `BinaryReader` does the looping for you.

If you wanted to not use `BinaryReader` for education purposes then make yourself a helper function that reads an exact number of bytes.

I would base `TcpMessageStream` on a `Stream`, not on `TcpClient`. That makes it more general.

The async usage is correct.

The dispose pattern that you have used is not useful here. The finalizer does nothing and there will never be any inheritors. There is no need for this boolean `disposed` flag. Write a normal `void Dispose()` method that just does what's needed.

All in all this is a very good job. Networking code is very hard.

If this is part of a real application consider not writing your own networking protocol at all. Try to use HTTP or websockets. Go as high in the abstraction stack as possible.